# Communicating with android app through usb

Tags: android, linux, usb

I'm trying to get my computer, which is running Linux, to send and receive data to and from an Android app using an USB cable. I tried using the `UsbDeviceConnection` class but the `usbdevice` object returns `null` and is not picking up my Android device. Is there is any fix for this or any other way to create a communication over USB?

Comment: are you sure there's no problem with your cable?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [ADB](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) (Android Debug Interface). It offers a number of useful tools to communicate with your Android device and apps on it. There are simple push/pull commands which allow you to move files back and forth between your computer and Android device, just to name a couple.

As far as your `usbdevice` object returning `null`, have you checked to see if USB Debugging is `On` on your device?

Also: here is a similar question that might help: [How can I send messages back and forth between ADB shell and an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076408/how-can-i-send-messages-back-and-forth-between-adb-shell-and-an-android-app)